# TeXmaker syntax highlighting problems

Tags: color, texmaker, highlighting, syntax, syntax-highlighting

can anyone tell me why TeXmaker is not coloring my code correctly?
For some reason everything below my `\newcommand`line is in text-colour.
When i paste my code into overleaf it works normally (https://www.overleaf.com/read/mvdrbxnhwcjj)

[image]

Comment: I think you should better try TeXstudio (my favorite TeX editor)

Comment: https://www.texstudio.org/

Comment: I know nothing about texmaker highlighting but note that `\lstinline`is a verb-like command and can not be used in a definition or argument of another command in that way.

Comment: your overleaf link shows [errors and no output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq7xy.png)

Comment: Please show code as text in a code block debugging an image is hard,  but you have 4 `{` on line 79 and only three `}` so line 82 is still part of the definition.